# ntddk.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, compiler-construction, build, codeblocks, device-driver

I am using `CODE::BLOCKS in windows XP`. Tried to write a device driver. But right after creating a project, I got below error. I did below settings, but still getting the error as 
"ntddk.h no such file or directory". I have tried with all compilers (Project built option), but it is still there.
Please help.

Created the project like:- `File->New->Project->Kernel Mode Driver->Next->Next...`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, like most people using Code::Blocks on Windows, you use MingW-TDM (commonly detected as "GNU GCC Compiler" by Code::Blocks, and bundled with the "easy install" package), the file `ntddk.h` is located in the `ddk` subfolder of the system include folder.

Thus, you either have to add the `ddk` folder to the include search path, or write `#include <ddk/ntddk.h>`, either will work.

Comment: I would like to write the device drive programs on USB. My program will inform me when USB is connected/disconnected. Read data from USB stick and all. Please guide me how can I do that. Are there any references online or something?

Comment: That would best be asked in a separate question, as it is entirely unrelated to the problem in this question. In the mean time, you might want to look at [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well as the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message for knowing when an USB stick is connected (normal program, no driver needed). Reading/writing is the exact same as with every disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your list of compilers does not seem to include the DDK compiler
2. Do you have the windows DDK installed?

NOTE: I know nothing about codeblocks but you will need the DDK compiler to compile windows drivers.